# pointing foreign key to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

is that possible to make foreign key from datetime datatype ?
i try this but i got error message : 
Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'penduduk' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'tgllahir'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

i use this query

PARENT TABLE :

```
create table penduduk (
no int identity(1,1),
noktp char(11) primary key,
nama varchar(20),
tgl_lahir datetime NOT NULL,
namahari varchar(20),
tgl int,
bulan int,
namabulan varchar(20),
tahun int,
umur int
)

CREATE TABLE tua(
noktp CHAR(11) PRIMARY KEY,
tgl_lahir datetime NOT NULL CONSTRAINT tgllahir FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES penduduk(tgl_lahir),
FOREIGN KEY(noktp) REFERENCES penduduk(noktp),
)
```

Comment: You are referencing penduduk(tgl_lahir) in tua table.but tgl_lahir is not primary key in penduduk table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table penduduk (
no int identity(1,1),
noktp char(11) primary key,
nama varchar(20),
tgl_lahir datetime NOT NULL unique,
namahari varchar(20),
tgl int,
bulan int,
namabulan varchar(20),
tahun int,
umur int
)

CREATE TABLE tua(
noktp CHAR(11) PRIMARY KEY,
tgl_lahir datetime NOT NULL CONSTRAINT tgllahir FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES penduduk(tgl_lahir),
FOREIGN KEY(noktp) REFERENCES penduduk(noktp),
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can only use a column as a reference in a Foreign Key constraint if it's a suitable candidate key.

From Books Online:

> A FOREIGN KEY constraint does not have to be linked only to a PRIMARY
>   KEY constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference
>   the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table.

See [Foreign Key Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

In your case `tgl_lahir` is neither Unique or a Primary so cannot be used in your Foreign Key constraint.

If you add a Unique constraint to `tgl_lahir` it should work; whether that's workable with your data is the real question.

Answer (score 3):

`penduduk.tgl_lahir` column needs to be defined as either a [primary key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191236%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) or with a [unique constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) to be referenced by a foreign key constraint.

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57466)